# How to make an unremovable modal window?

Tags: notebooks, gui-construction, dialog-window

Is there any way to securely stick a notebook window (e.g. a dialog) on screen that it cannot be closed/removed/hidden by any of the standard OS shortcuts, like <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F4</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> under Windows? The ideal solution would allow me to specify a range of key-combinations that can be used, and block any other, though it would not be a problem to block *all* keyboard input, as there are other ways to close a modal dialog.

I have a feeling that this cannot be done entirely from under *Mathematica*, though I'll give it a go. You can experiment with the following example:

```
CreateDialog[{TextCell["Click OK to close"], DefaultButton[]}, Modal -> True]
```

**Purpose**: I'm doing some experimentation on humans in *Mathematica*, and since this species is known by its extensive explorative behaviour (i.e. pushing all buttons) and the ability to ruin everything, I want to make the experiment-gui foolproof so that they can't remove it from the screen. This is a must, as it could happen that they hit <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F4</kbd> (accidentally or intentionally) and quit at the middle of a test, rendering any saved data useless.

Comment: I guess you figured out that `WindowFrameElements -> {}` doesn't prevent Alt-F4 from working.

Comment: Not sure this is a Mathematica-specific question? Maybe people over on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) might have ideas that can then be implemented in MMA?

Comment: @Szabolcs Setting `WindowFrameElements -> {}` does prevent `Cmd-w` from closing the notebook on OS X.

Comment: I now how to do it in [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/), though I would prefer a domestic solution.

Comment: @Heike that doesn't help for `Alt-F4`

Comment: @Heike On Windows, it does help `Ctrl-W`, but not `Alt-F4`.

Comment: @Szabolcs I don't think OS X has an `Alt-F4` equivalent apart from `Cmd-W` and possibly `Cmd-H` (which hides all windows of the active application (at least on 10.6))

Comment: @EliLansey I realise that. I just thought it curious that the behaviour is different for a different OS.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is a good idea in principle, regardless of whether it can be done in *Mathematica* or not. As [Raymond Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/) frequently asks: "what if two people did this?"

Comment: @OleksandrR., please see my edit. I don't think there is any other clever solution than simply suppressing all shortcuts.

Comment: Okay, that seems reasonable. Have you considered running the notebook in the *Mathematica* browser plugin, using a browser that has a [kiosk mode](http://www.opera.com/support/mastering/kiosk/)?

Comment: @Oleksandr That is a good idea, though I am afraid that deploying my stuff for the plugin might not be a straightforward task. If you could just post it as an answer with some details, I could accept it if no direct in-Mathematica solution appears.

Comment: I'm reluctant to post that as an answer because I haven't actually tried it and don't have all the details worked out. For example, I had thought that if you have full *Mathematica* installed and open a notebook rather than a CDF, the restrictions disappear. But now that I test it, that's not the case (and I can't work out how to change that either). If I figure it out, *then* I'll post an answer. :)

Comment: I will appreciate that :) In the meanwhile, I will do my research as well.

Answer (score 10):

Not 100% solution, but this may work. Define:

```
dialog := 
 CreateDialog[{TextCell["Click OK to close"], DefaultButton[]}, 
  Modal -> True, NotebookEventActions -> {"WindowClose" :> dialog}]
```

Then call:

```
dialog
```

At least, it reappears :)

Comment: Devilish workaround :) But unfortunately it does not prevent accidental Alt+Tab changes and similar non-invasive key combinations which simply just hide the window.