# After executing MessageDialog[] how can I wait for it to close before continuing

Tags: dialog-window

After executing MessageDialog[] how can I wait for it to close before continuing?
I want to popup up a message and wait for the user to hit OK before continuing.  Is there a mechanism for this?

Comment: `CreateDialog` has the option to set `Modal->True` which will freeze Mathematica until the user interacts with the dialog.  `MessageDialog` does not appear to have this feature.

Comment: [related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4468/7167)

Comment: `ChoiceDialog` similarly has blocking behavior.

Comment: @bobthechemist `MessageDialog` *does* have this feature despite the warning message.  The option does have an effect.  I think that the message might be a bug in v9 ...

Comment: @Szabolcs silly me for believing the front end.

Answer (score 3):

If what you are looking for is the ability to halt access to the notebook (or the Mathematica front end in general), then you want to set `Modal->True` in the MessageDialog options.

```
MessageDialog["Click to Continue", Modal->True]
```

As mentioned in the comments, Model does not appear to be a valid option for `MessageDialog`; however, it works.  It does throw an error, and if you want to keep your notebook clean something like this is needed:

```
Quiet@MessageDialog["Click to continue", Modal-> True]
```

You can also use `CreateDialog`, which has the documented Modal behavior; however the downfall of this approach is that you have to create the dialog box in its entirety (this function does not come with a default button):

```
CreateDialog[Column@{"Click to continue", DefaultButton[]},Modal->True]
```

In both cases, omitting the Modal option will allow the user to change the focus of the Mathematica front end to another notebook, the Mathematica toolbar, or the notebook that called the Dialog box in the first place.

Comment: If I enter `MessageDialog["bla", Modal->True];MessageDialog["blaa", Modal->True]` I get two dialogs at once. If I enter `Input[];Input[]`, I get one input window and then the other after I close the first. Can I make a dialog window behave like this?

Comment: @Blrp The documentation states that `MessageDialog` returns immediately and `Input` stops the Wolfram System.  I suspect creating a dialog with the same behavior would require customization and is not currently a built-in function.

Answer (score 1):

```
error = "409";
MessageDialog[error]
```

Comment: `MessageDialog` allows the user to refocus the notebook that called it, and subsequently evaluate cells; as I interpret the OPs question, s/he wishes to halt this behavior.

Comment: I discovered that ChoiceDialog[] has the "blocking" property but I do not see how to set this in general.

Comment: @user16082 What do you mean by "set in general"?

Comment: When ChoiceDialog[] is evaluated, the command immediately following is not evaluated until the dialog is closed.  This is the 'blocking' behavior I would like to have for other dialogs such as the more general CreateDialog[].  Setting Modal->True does prevent the user from accessing interface elements outside the dialog but does not stop the kernel from evaluating the statement(s) immediately following the CreateDialog[] command.